# Ember-Data Fixture Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a commit method for the fixture adapter? What does it do?
As my understanding goes `store.commit()` puts an API call when used with REST adapter.

Can I use `isLoaded` property with fixture adapter?

Basically I have 2 records in my controller called `x` and `y` and a property content that has many records of `y` type.
Coffee code below:

```coffeescript
someMethod: (->
  content.removeObject(y)
).('x.isLoaded')

anotherMethod: ->
  //modify x
  Application.store.commit()
```

When I call `anotherMethod` it updates `x` and runs a commit on store, hence `someMethod` gets called.
My actual application runs fine but in case of tests `someMethod` removes the record `y` from content as well as store.
Is it that `isLoaded` and `commit` are not for fixture data store?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a commit method and it is accessible through [DS.Store](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L829) or DS.Transaction.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/Adw4F/32/) that has some good code that quickly demonstrates CRUD with fixtures.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 4,
    adapter: 'DS.fixtureAdapter'
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
})

App.Person.FIXTURES = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Fixture object 1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Fixture object 2'}
];

App.people = App.store.findAll(App.Person);
App.store.createRecord(App.Person, {id: 1, name: 'Created person'});

App.personView = Em.View.extend({
    isVisibleBinding: 'notDeleted',
    notDeleted: function() {
        return !this.getPath('person.isDeleted');
    }.property('person.isDeleted').cacheable(),

    remove: function () {
      this.get('person').deleteRecord();
    }
});
```