# Ember data store return undefined record from FIXTURES

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, single-page-application

I am new in ember and i am trying to simply get log of items stored by Fixtures model and i cannot. Here is what I have done:

app.js

```
    App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
        adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()
    });

    App.Documenter = DS.Model.extend({
        firstName: DS.attr('string'),
        lastName: DS.attr('string')
    });

    App.Documenter.FIXTURES = [
      { id: 1, firstName: 'Trek', lastName: 'Glowacki' },
      { id: 2, firstName: 'Tom', lastName: 'Dale' }
    ];


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    controllerName: 'application',
    actions: {
        addtostore: function () {
        },
        displaystore: function () {
             var obj =  this.store.all('documenter');
            console.log(obj.objectAt(0).firstName); //here i get undefined

        }
    }

});
```

html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Ember POC</h2>
    <p>POC</p>
    {{outlet}}
     <button {{action 'displaystore'}}>TestButton</button>
</script>
```

I've looked at few answers already on stackoverflow:
[Ember-Data Fixture Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386913/ember-data-fixture-adapter)
[Ember App Kit with ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742647/ember-app-kit-with-ember-data)

but still I dont get, why button `TestButton` dont log into console. I tried many ways but always it is undefined

Comment: Have you tried `obj.objectAt(0).get("firstName")` instead of access the property directly?

Comment: Use the Ember debugger and make sure your objects are in the store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to define the store, and your adapter should be defined like so:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
```

And `all` only returns records that have already been found and are in the store.  The FIXTURES hash isn't automatically loaded into the store, you still need to use `find` in order to get records from the FIXTURES hash.

```
displaystore: function () {
    this.store.find('documenter').then(function(records){ // this is async
      console.log(records.get('firstObject.firstName'));
    });
}
```

It's doubtful you would want to call `find` from the action like this, since it'd call back to the server each time, generally you'd get the records in the route (or even prime your store in the route so you can use `all`).

Comment: it was helpfull and i needed to do such thing too, but i did so many things wrong that i will write after that answere

Answer (score 0):

Because I am fresh in Ember, I made few common mistakes. I did not understand routes, handlebars, etc., and I messed up. The problem was that I did not assign the model to a controller.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        var store = this.get('store');
        return store.findAll('documenter');
    }
});
```